How to call a library in Jupyter notebook while install that by Conda (GitHub web Codespaces)
I am trying to install and run a library in GitHub web codespaces. I installed the library via the following command line in the terminal and it seems it was installed correctly.
conda install --channel conda-forge pygcgopt

...
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2024.7.2-h~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2024.8.30-hbcca054_0 
  conda              pkgs/main::conda-24.7.1-py312h06a4308~ --> conda-forge::conda-24.9.2-py312h7900ff3_0 
  libgcc-ng          pkgs/main::libgcc-ng-11.2.0-h1234567_1 --> conda-forge::libgcc-ng-14.2.0-h69a702a_1 
  libgomp              pkgs/main::libgomp-11.2.0-h1234567_1 --> conda-forge::libgomp-14.2.0-h77fa898_1 
  libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main::libstdcxx-ng-11.2.0-h12345~ --> conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng-14.2.0-h4852527_1 
  libuuid              pkgs/main::libuuid-1.41.5-h5eee18b_0 --> conda-forge::libuuid-2.38.1-h0b41bf4_0 
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-3.0.15-h5eee18b_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-3.4.0-hb9d3cd8_0 
  zlib                    pkgs/main::zlib-1.2.13-h5eee18b_1 --> conda-forge::zlib-1.2.13-h4ab18f5_6 

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  _libgcc_mutex           pkgs/main::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main --> conda-forge::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-conda_forge 
  _openmp_mutex          pkgs/main::_openmp_mutex-5.1-1_gnu --> conda-forge::_openmp_mutex-4.5-2_gnu 
  certifi            pkgs/main/linux-64::certifi-2024.8.30~ --> conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2024.8.30-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  python                pkgs/main::python-3.12.3-h996f2a0_1 --> conda-forge::python-3.12.2-hab00c5b_0_cpython 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages:
                                                                                                                                
Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                     
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                     
Executing transaction: done                                                                                                     
@AbbasOmidi ➜ /workspaces/PyGCGOpt (master) $ 

In the next step, I selected Kernel install/selected Python + Jupyter. Then I chose the Python environment. Actually Global env = python 3.12.1. Now, when I run the code cell that contains the library import method, I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 from pygcgopt import Model, quicksum
      3 def build_model(n_locations, n_clusters, distances, demands, capacities):
      4     m = Model()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygcgopt'

Could you please, how can I fix that and run the model?
